# Is there a way to dynamically change the name of a command with an extra input in the class?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7, discord.py

Here is my code :

```py
    @commands.group(name=f'{prefix}stop', hidden=True)
    @commands.is_owner()
    async def stop(self, ctx):

        await ctx.message.add_reaction('\N{THUMBS UP SIGN}')
        await self.bot.logout()
        sys.exit()
```

I'd like to know if there is a way to include a prefix inside the name of the command.

I tried adding an extra input in the `__init__` like so : `__init__(self, bot, prefix='')` to be able to manage if I want a prefix or not. And then, for the name I tried `f'{self.prefix}stop'` but it returns me `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your `group` decorator is evaluated when the class is created, not when the instance is.  However, since `Cog.__new__` creates copies of the groups/commands for each instance, we can modify the name inside `Cog.__init__`:

```
from discord.ext import commands

class MyCog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot, prefix=''):
        self.stop.name = prefix + self.stop.name

    @commands.group(hidden=True)
    async def stop(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send(self.stop.name)
```

Comment: `discord.errors.ClientException: Command stop is already registered.` if I do not have any prefixes, so I had to add a little condition `if prefix:` before `self.stop.name = [...]`

Comment: Interesting. Do you already have a `stop` command defined somewhere else?

Comment: Actually, no. I think discord.py was trying to assign `self.stop.name` to `self.stop.name` and it seems that he didn't really like it.

Comment: But is there a way to attribute that particular prefix to all commands ?

Comment: @Sehn [Look at how the `Cog.__new__` method updates the commands](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/discord/ext/commands/cog.py#L161).